# Invalid Column Name with INNER JOIN and Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, t-sql, ssms

Im currently writing a stored procedure in SQL to print results from multiple tables to find the top ten products purchased, but I am getting the syntax error

"Invalid column name 'ProductID'".

This appears on the 2nd INNER JOIN statement at sod.ProductID

My code below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_top10ProfitableProducts
AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT TOP 10 sp.StoreProductID, sup.ProductName, sum(sod.Quantity) AS quantitysold, (sum(sod.Quantity) * sum(sod.unitPrice)) - (sum(sod.Quantity) * sum(sp.costPrice)) AS Profit
FROM SalesOrderDetails sod
INNER JOIN StoreProduct sp ON sp.StoreProductID = sod.StoreProductID
INNER JOIN SupplierProduct sup ON sup.ProductID = sod.ProductID
WHERE Quantity > 0
END
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT** Below is also my Entity Relationship diagram. 'ProductID' lives in 'SupplierProduct'

[image]

Comment: Is there a `ProductID` column in `SalesOrderDetails`?

Comment: doesn't have a StoreProductID"SalesOrderDetails sod" and doesn't have ProductID

Comment: I think your table structure is not enough to get the result query..

Comment: No theres no `ProductID` in `SalesOrderDetails`. But i thought that INNER JOIN wouldn't connect those tables. Or is this not how inner join works?

Comment: Do the `storeproductid` and `supplierproductid` agree with each other? Is it the same `id` in the `storeproduct` and `supplierproduct` tables for any given item?

Comment: Or, what is the full field list for the `SalesOrderDetails` table.

Comment: Sorry for multiple comments. Just saw you tagged `mysql`. Should that be `ms-sql` i.e. `sql-server`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the field does not exist in one of the tables. Another point: group by was missing.

```
GROUP BY sp.StoreProductID, sup.ProductName
```

Comment: Yeh i finally added that. Still hasn't solved my issue. Thanks anyway.. :)

Answer (score 0):

To do a join between two tables the joining column (in above case ProductID) should be available in both tables, otherwise sql will not be able to do the join.
According to the table structure SalesOrderDetails doesn't have a column ProductID which is why it's giving the error, you need to the join on cloumns that exist in the respective tables

Comment: Thanks. The DB has been updated and is working. Thanks